# Get Grand Total From Rows Total

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I'm confused on how would i select all total on all rows and automatically calculate it in the grand total? Like what i did in the total, i just get the values of price and quantity but how can select all so i can able to calculate automatically. How can i add the grand total of all total row?

> html

```
<div class="card-block" formArrayName="rows">
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Material SKU</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Total</th>
        <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let row of myForm.controls.rows.controls; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
        <td>
          <select formControlName="material_id" class="col-md-10" required>
            <option *ngFor="let mat_order of mat_orders" [ngValue]="mat_order.material_id">
              {{ mat_order.mat_name }}
            </option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td><input type="number" class="col-md-6" formControlName="quantity" required></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="col-md-6" formControlName="price" required></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="col-md-6" formControlName="total"  [ngModel] ="row.get('quantity').value * row.get('price').value" required></td>
        <td>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" (click)="onDeleteRow(i)"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Remove</button>
        </td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div class="float-right">
    Grand Total:  <input type="number" class="col-md-5" formControlName="grand_total" required disabled>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary float-left" (click)="initGroup()"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>  Add Row</button>
</div>
```

> ts

```
 constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { 

    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      rows: this.fb.array([])
    })

  }


initGroup() {
    let rows = this.myForm.get('rows') as FormArray;
    rows.push(this.fb.group({
      material_id: [''],
      quantity: [''],
      price: [''],
      total: ['']
    }))

  }
```

Comment: you have an `input` for grand_total..Do you want user to insert or display as text?

Comment: just display it, user cannot input in it. input is disabled. It is automatically calculated from all total rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use Array `map` and `reduce` here.

```
Grand Total:  <input type="number" class="col-md-5" formControlName="grand_total" [ngModel]="calculateTotal()" required disabled>
```

In your ts file:

```
calculateTotal():number{
    let rows = this.myForm.get('rows') as FormArray;
   return rows.controls.
      map((row)=> row.get('quantity').value * row.get('price').value). //calcualte each amount
       reduce((sum,amount) => sum + amount,0); //find sum
}
```

Comment: It says property controls does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'

Comment: I think  it needs to be typecasted.. you are using a  formArray within your form

Comment: Another error is Error: Cannot find control with path: 'rows -> grand_total'

Comment: that is related to your `formControlName` you set in your html.. have you set that in your formbuilder?

Comment: Yes i did.  this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      rows: this.fb.array([]),
      reference: new FormControl(''),
      date: new FormControl(''),
      grand_total : new FormControl('')
    })

Comment: Maybe it's in the html?

Comment: you have set the input grand_total inside `<div class="card-block" formArrayName="rows">`

Comment: no it needs to be _outside_ formArrayName="rows" since your formbuilder creates it as a control outside rows. You need to debug your code

Comment: Why i can't het value of grand_total?

Comment: I did this  this.grand_total = this.myForm.get('grand_total').value

Comment: Change the [value] to [ngModel]

Comment: are you are using template forms along with reactive form?

Comment: Well, [ngModel] works. i can display the value of grand_total to other forms when i used it

Answer (score 0):

Create and function in component something like

```
calculateGrandTotal():number:{
return myForm.controls.rows.controls.sum()
 var total = 0
    myForm.controls.rows.controls.forEach( function(item){
      total+=item.quantity.value*item.price.value
    })
    return total
}
```

Then in html

```
 <div class="float-right">
  Grand Total:{{calculateGrandTotal()}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
**Angular 6: Grand Total**       
 **<h2 align="center">Usage Details Of {{profile$.firstName}}</h2>
        <table align ="center">
          <tr>
            <th>Call Usage</th>
            <th>Data Usage</th>
            <th>SMS Usage</th>
            <th>Total Bill</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <tr *ngFor="let user of bills$">
            <td>{{ user.callUsage}}</td>
            <td>{{ user.dataUsage }}</td>
            <td>{{ user.smsUsage }}</td>
       <td>{{user.callUsage *2 + user.dataUsage *1 + user.smsUsage *1}}</td>
          </tr>


          <tr>
            <th> </th>
            <th>Grand Total</th>
            <th></th>
            <td>{{total( bills$)}}</td>
          </tr>
        </table>**


    **Controller:**
        total(bills) {
            var total = 0;
            bills.forEach(element => {
total = total + (element.callUsage * 2 + element.dataUsage * 1 + element.smsUsage * 1);
            });
            return total;
        }
```

Comment: Please, add some explanations to your code for a better understanding of it!